# Changeable LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: bash, path

I'd like to choose openmpi as my parallel c compiler and has added it to my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in **.profile**. When I compiled a code, it worked and produced a .o file. But when I ran the .o file an error appeared:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmpi.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My colleague told me perhaps I hadn't added the openmpi lib right. I checked my **.profile** and did some tricks, the corresponding clip is as follows:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/apps/openmpi-1.4.3/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
echo
echo "HERE is .profile!"
echo
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
echo
```

Then I exited and logged in again, it said:

```
HERE is .profile!

/apps/openmpi-1.4.3/lib:/usr/...
```

However, when I typed in the terminal `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, the **/apps/openmpi…** part is missing, only the rest remained. The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is changeable so fast?
I have tried to execute another command:

```
. .profile
```

The "openmpi" part came out again and the .o file worked smoothly.
What causes the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` different? As far as I know, the **.profile** is a login shell.
ps: I use MAC osX and bash.

@jherran: I have tried what you said, but it seems not working. Actually I once add the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my .bashrc and .bash_profile. Add another line in .profile:

```
[ -r ~/.bashrc ] && source ~/.bashrc
```

I tested it again just now. Delete the LD line in .profile and added it into .bash_profile and exited then logged in. This time, echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH won't output …openmpi. But the same if I typed 
`. .bash_profile`

it works!

OK, just come to update the news, the reason why the above condition appeared I still can't find, finally I turned to another parallel compiler mpich. Everything settled!

Comment: Try to set it up in `/etc/environment`? LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/apps/openmpi-1.4.3/lib

Comment: @jherran:No, I'm working on a cluster and not authorised to make any changes to the files under the root directory. I don't think it should be so mysterious because my colleagues they never met with such problems. T_T.

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting the PATH, and probably this will be overwritten later.

You need to add your code to your `~/.bash_profile`. It is the personal initialisation file, executed for login shells.

Comment: I know that, but I'm sure in my occasion `.bashrc`is executed so this is not the problem.